Cannot read property "x" of undefined
In a react native app, I am mapping with FlashList through Checkboxes that add or remove them from a state array when clicked.
And when clicking one of the already selected checkboxes, I am getting the following error:
Cannot read property "x" of undefined from FlashList.
Some guy on the internet suggested to create a copy of the array, and pass it to FlashList data prop, but I can't make it work.
Where the code breaks:
<FlashList
  data={[...(scheduleData[1] as number[])]}
  estimatedItemSize={256}
  extraData={{ scheduleData, setScheduleData }}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <OrderCard
      data={orders.find(({ id }) => id === item)!}
      index={index}
      scheduleData={scheduleData}
      setScheduleData={setScheduleData}
    />
  )}
/>

It works fine with regular .map()

Is it a typo in the OrderCard component? Could you paste the code where you're trying to access the property x in OrderCard?

@sj_959 I'm not trying to access any property, let alone one called "x". The error occurs only when using FlashList
